# Using Ifnull in Subquery SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I've this two tables, members and water_meter

members

```
id | name
=========
1  | Dani
2  | Dina
3  | Roni
```

water_meter

```
id | member_id  | date      | start | finish    | paid  |   paid_at
===+============+===========+=======+===========+=======+=====================+
1  |    1       |2014-07-01 |  12.3 |   38.7    |   1   | 2014-12-29 18:28:30
2  |    2       |2014-07-01 |  57.2 |   64.3    |   0   | null
3  |    3       |2014-07-01 |  14.6 |   52.3    |   0   | null
```

This member need to pay their water usage every month. What I want is, the 'start' value of each month is the 'finish' value from previous months. This is my query to check water usage at August,

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
ifnull(t.start, (SELECT ifnull(finish, 0) FROM members m2 
LEFT JOIN water_meter t2 ON m2.id = t2.member_id AND t2.date = '2014-07-01') ) as start, 
t.finish, paid
FROM members m 
LEFT JOIN water_meter t ON m.id = t.member_id AND t.date = '2014-08-01'
```

Result :

```
id | name   | start  |  finish |
===+========+========+=========+
1  |  Dani  | 38.7   |   null  |
2  |  Dina  | 38.7   |   null  |
3  |  Roni  | 38.7   |   null  |
```

As you can see, the "start" value is not right. What is the right query for this case?

What I want is like this

```
id | name   | start  |  finish |
===+========+========+=========+
1  |  Dani  | 38.7   |   null  |
2  |  Dina  | 64.3   |   null  |
3  |  Roni  | 52.3   |   null  |
```

Check : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/29a4c/2

Comment: Not enough data to understand your problem (well, at least for me). Please add rows for august and your desired output.

Comment: August is new data in this case, so if the user hasn't added new data yet for august, I need to make the "start" of August as "finish" field of July. I updated my question the include my expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned correct `where` condition in inner query.

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
  ifnull(t.start,
         (SELECT ifnull(finish, 0) FROM members m2 
          LEFT JOIN water_meter t2
            ON m2.id = t2.member_id AND t2.date = '2014-07-01'
          where m2.id = m.id)) as start, 
  t.finish, paid
FROM members m 
LEFT JOIN water_meter t ON m.id = t.member_id AND t.date = '2014-08-01'
WHERE m.active = 1
```

I don't like query itself, but that produces the output you wanted.

A little better (no subqueries, which may be slow on large dataset) solution:

```
select
  members.id,
  name,
  coalesce(wm_cur.start, wm_prev.finish),
  wm_cur.finish
from members
left join water_meter wm_cur
  on members.id = wm_cur.member_id
    and wm_cur.date between '2014-08-01' and date('2014-08-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
left join water_meter wm_prev
  on members.id = wm_prev.member_id
    and wm_prev.date between '2014-07-01' and date('2014-07-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
where members.active = 1
```

You can replace `coalesce` with `ifnull` if you wish. It also handles entire month and not only first day, which may or may not be what you want it to be.

Comment: Do you have any better solution for this case? And also thank you for your answer